# Fields doesn't sent inside form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have this code and I don't understand why the products_twitter is not sent like the others fields. The element is inside thr form balise

Summary of the page generated

```
<form name="products_specials" action="http://......./index.php?A&Products%5CSpecials&Specials&Insert" method="post">
<a href="......../index.php?A&Products%5CSpecials&Specials&Specials&page=1" target="_self" class="btn btn-warning">Annuler</a>&nbsp;
<button type="submit" class="btn  btn-success">Insérer</button>


        <div class="mainTitle">Informations sur le produit</div>
        <div class="adminformTitle" id="tab1Specials">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="Produit :" class="col-5 col-form-label">Produit :</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                  <select name="products_id" class="form-control" />
<option value="16">Bureau d'accueil (Client Normal: &nbsp;1.00&nbsp;EUR - Tarifs 1 : &nbsp;0.95&nbsp;EUR)
</option>
                  </select>
                  <input type="hidden" name="products_price" />                
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>


<!-- the problem is here appear inside the form but not sent (products_twitter) -->

<!--  Start TwitterApp      -->
<script>
$('#tab1Specials').append(
    '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group row"><label for="Souhaitez-vous publier ce produit sur Twitter ?" class="col-5 col-form-label">Souhaitez-vous publier ce produit sur Twitter ?</label><div class="col-md-5"><input type="radio" name="products_twitter" id="products_twitter" value="1" />&nbsp;Oui&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="products_twitter" id="products_twitter" value="on" />&nbsp;Non</div></div></div></div>'
);
</script>
<!--  End TwitterApp      -->
  </form>
```

the code between start twitter and end twitter is these elements : I call the element with an `include`.

```
       $content1 = '<div class="row">';
       $content1 .= '<div class="col-md-5">';
       $content1 .= '<div class="form-group row">';
       $content1 .= '<label for="' . $this->app->getDef('text_twitter') . '" class="col-5 col-form-label">' . $this->app->getDef('text_twitter') . '</label>';
       $content1 .= '<div class="col-md-5">';
       $content1 .= HTML::radioField('products_twitter', '1', $pInfo->in_accept_twitter) . '&nbsp;' . $this->app->getDef('text_yes') . '&nbsp;' . HTML::radioField('products_twitter', '0', $pInfo->out_accept_twitter) . '&nbsp;' . $this->app->getDef('text_no');
       $content1 .= '</div>';
       $content1 .= '</div>';
       $content1 .= '</div>';
       $content1 .= '</div>';

      $output = <<<EOD
<!--  Start TwitterApp      -->
<script>
$('#tab1Specials').append(
    '{$content1}'
    );
    </script>
    <!--  end TwitterApp      -->
EOD;
```

the only element sent are (`$_POST`):

```
array(6) { ["products_id"]=> string(2) "16" ["products_price"]=> string(0) "" ["specials_price"]=> string(2) "10" ["customers_group"]=> string(0) "" ["schdate"]=> string(0) "" ["expdate"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: does your code contain the closing `EOD` identifier?

Comment: look at your developer console and use php's error reporting

Comment: yes, I forgot for this element, I add

Comment: All your radio buttons have the same ID, which is not valid in HTML. I don't think it'll stop the values from being submitted in the form, but all the same you should change it

Comment: btw why are you using PHP to generate HTML to place into a JS command in order for JS append the content to the page as soon as it loads? You could just inject the HTML immediately using PHP without this level of indirection

Comment: Anyway, it's not clear what the issue is...see this demo using your exact code above: http://jsfiddle.net/ryd75o6z/ - the radio button is shown, and when you click "Inserer" to submit the form, the request is submitted and the radio button value is sent - the request body looks like this, for example: `products_id=16&products_price=&products_twitter=1`. Also, there are variables missing which are shown in your example $_POST output above...are you sure you're looking at the right output? Your code above does not reproduce the stated problem.

Comment: P.S. Having posted those comments I've just noticed this is an old question which was just edited recently (and so showed up in my feed). I've voted to close it since it doesn't demonstrate the problem. But I guess maybe you solved it a while ago anyway.